# How do you share an instance of an enum between different translation units in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, linker-errors

I am setting up a state system for my game and encountered a problem regarding Enums. What I am trying to do is to define an instance of the APP_STATE enum and share it between different translation units.

Code:

```
// APP_STATE.h

 #pragma once
 enum class APP_STATE : signed char { RUNNING = 2, LOAD = 1, EXIT = 0, FORCE_QUIT = -1 };

// Source.cpp

#include "APP_STATE.h"
APP_STATE appState = APP_STATE::RUNNING;

// Other.cpp

#include "APP_STATE.h"

namespace other {
    extern APP_STATE appState;

    void foo () {
        appState = APP_STATE::EXIT; // causes a LNK1120 and LNK2001 error, unresolved extrernal symbol
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet the error was complaining about `other::appState` (or some mangled form thereof) not being defined. That could have tipped you off.

Comment: I tried extern ::APP_STATE appState with the suspicion of it being relative to namespaces, however it did not occur to me that I could simply extract the declaration to outside the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined *two* different instances of `APP_STATE`:

- One is named `::appState`: it's in the global namespace, declared in `APP_STATE.h` and defined in `Source.cpp`.
- The other is named `other::appState`: it's in namespace `other`, declared in `Other.cpp` but never defined, hence the error.

In `Other.cpp`, you should move the declaration of `extern APP_STATE appState;` outside of the namespace:

```
// Other.cpp

#include "APP_STATE.h"

extern APP_STATE appState;

namespace other {

    void foo () {
        appState = APP_STATE::EXIT;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thank you for your swift answer. It did not occur to me that the extern keyword would behave differently inside of a namespace (relative to to the namespace).

Comment: @Soimn It doesn't behave differently at all. It declares (but not defines) a variable in the namespace in which it appears. Just every other unqualified declaration, actually.